# Is there a guarantee the stack won't be cleaned after a block enclosed by brackets?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory

My question is: Do I have a guarantee the compiler won't clean up a variable from the stack after a block in brackets is finished?

I have this snippet:

```
void someMethod() {
    Bar* barPtr;
    if (foo != null) {
        Bar bar = { foo->a, foo->b };  // (a)
        barPtr = &bar;                
    }                                 
    else {
        barPtr = nullptr;
    }

    Bar bar2 = { 42, 4711 }; // (c)
    doSomethingElse(&bar2);

    doSomething(barPtr); // (b)
}
```

Notice `bar` is valid only in the upper block (a)  whereas `barPtr` is valid in the whole method. At (b) `bar` is not in scope anymore.

- Is it save to use `barPtr` at this point?
- Or is the compiler allowed to reuse that memory `bar` is stored for further local variables defined in (c)?

Comment: You can do whatever you want with `barPtr` at *(b)*, as long as you don't dereference it. And yes, the compiler is allowed to resuse the storage for an object after the lifetime of that object has ended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You asked:

> Is there a guarantee the stack won't be cleaned after a block enclosed by brackets?

The guarantee is the other way around. There is a guarantee that the stack will be cleaned after a block enclosed by brackets to the extent that automatic variables will be destructed.

```
Bar* barPtr;
if (foo != null) {
    Bar bar = { foo->a, foo->b };  // (a)
    barPtr = &bar;

   // bar is destructed after the block ends.                
}
```

At the end of the block, `barPtr` points to dangling memory.

Comment: Well there's no guarantee of *cleaning*. But the pointer value is invalid after the block. That's called a dangling pointer.

Answer (score 3):

The memory can be reused, and even if it hasn't been, you can't touch it.  Your object is DEAD, its destructor ran at the end of its scope.

Standard says (3.8)

> Before  the  lifetime  of  an  object  has  started  but  after  the  storage  which  the  object  will  occupy  has  been allocated or, after the lifetime of an object has ended and before the storage which the object occupied is reused or released, any pointer that refers to the storage location where the object will be or was located may be used but only in limited ways.

...

> The program has undefined behavior if:

...

> - the pointer is used to access a non-static data member or call a non-static member function of the object

You can use the pointer (which is an address), but you can't dereference it safely.

Comment: I mean, I just like standard quotes in general, and the effort. :)

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: I agree, see the first sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing an object after its lifetime has ended is Undefined Behavior.

Instead, replace this original code:

```
void someMethod() {
    Bar* barPtr;
    if (foo != null) {
        Bar bar = { foo->a, foo->b };  // (a)
        barPtr = &bar;                
    }                                 
    else {
        barPtr = nullptr;
    }

    Bar bar2 = { 42, 4711 }; // (c)
    doSomethingElse(&bar2);

    doSomething(barPtr); // (b)
}
```

… with this:

```
void someMethod() {
    auto const doThings = []( Bar* barPtr ) -> void
    {
        Bar bar2 = { 42, 4711 }; // (c)
        doSomethingElse(&bar2);

        doSomething(barPtr); // (b)
    };

    if (foo != null) {
        Bar bar = { foo->a, foo->b };  // (a)
        doThings( &bar );               
    }                                 
    else {
        doThings( nullptr );
    }
}
```

Or, any other refactoring that you like.